# How do I parse an XML file that is not well-formed

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I could not parse the XML file. How can I make the following code in the loop.
Can I do this with SimpleXML?

```
<Variants>
<Definition>Color=Black</Definition>
<Code/>
<Image>1744.jpg</Image>
<Stock>1</Stock>
<Price>3385.5933</Price>
<CurrencyID>1</CurrencyID>
<Suffix>TL</Suffix>
<Definition>Color=White</Definition>
<Code/>
<Image>1741.jpg</Image>
<Stock>1</Stock>
<Price>3385.5933</Price>
<CurrencyID>1</CurrencyID>
<Suffix>TL</Suffix>
</Variants>
```

Php Code

```
$xmlobj = simplexml_load_file("variants.xml");
$variants = $xmlobj->Variants;

foreach ($variants as $item) {
    echo " ".$item->Definition." ";
}
```

Comment: Have you actually tried using SimpleXML? It collects the recurring elements nicely in arrays. Show your coding attempts and explain your difficulties please.

Comment: I've added the code I wrote. I doing wrong? @mario

Comment: There's no such thing as an XML file that isn't well-formed. If it's not well-formed then it isn't XML. Your XML might be badly-designed, but that's not the same as being ill-formed.

Comment: (1) http://www.xmlvalidation.com - the XML you posted **is** valid. (2) what EXACTLY did not work? error-message? output received vs. output desired?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your XML is perfectly valid, do it like this:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($x); // assuming XML in $x
foreach ($xml->Definition as $def) echo "$def<br />";
```

see it working: http://codepad.viper-7.com/7g5nm8

Your code is failing because `<Variants>`is root and represented by `$xml`

Answer (score 0):

Use [`print_r($xmlobj)`](http://php.net/print_r) to see the actual SimpleXML structure and discover where you can iterate over what:

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [Definition] => Array
        (
            [0] => Color=Black
            [1] => Color=White
        )

    [Code] => Array
        (
            [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                )

            [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                )

        )

    [Image] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1744.jpg
            [1] => 1741.jpg
        )

    [Stock] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 1
        )

    [Price] => Array
        (
            [0] => 3385.5933
            [1] => 3385.5933
        )

    [CurrencyID] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 1
        )

    [Suffix] => Array
        (
            [0] => TL
            [1] => TL
        )
 )
```

In the simplest of cases you can iterate over one property each:

```
foreach ($xmlobject->Definition as $i=>$item) {
    echo " $item ";
}
```

If you want to retransform the spread structure into groups again, use:

```
foreach (json_decode(json_encode($xmlobject)) as $key=>$items) {
    foreach ($items as $i=>$entry) {
        $out["$i"]["$key"] = $entry;
    }
}
```

Which will give you:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Definition] => Color=Black
            [Code] => stdClass Object
                (
                )    
            [Image] => 1744.jpg
            [Stock] => 1
            [Price] => 3385.5933
            [CurrencyID] => 1
            [Suffix] => TL
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [Definition] => Color=White
            [Code] => stdClass Object
                (
                )    
            [Image] => 1741.jpg
            [Stock] => 1
            [Price] => 3385.5933
            [CurrencyID] => 1
            [Suffix] => TL
        )
)
```